# How to clear the stack on a SingleTop SingleInstance MainActivity on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, single-instance, android-task

I am trying to clear every single activity on the stack by `startActivity` method with the `Intent` flags:                      `(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)`

(I have an exit button that resets and finishes all activities and I tried all "how to make an exit button, how to terminate an app" questions/answers. They don't help me because of the `singleInstance` `launchMode` configuration of `MainActivity`.

Normally this should work and finish current activity automatically without calling `finish()`. However, as I marked MainActivity as `singleInstance` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, it doesn't work. If I remove that `singleInstance`, it works as expected.

If I call `finish()` manually right after/before launching the `MainActivity` to clear all the stack, `finish()`will return the app to the previous activity on the stack. But I already launched the `MainActivity`. So everything gets messed.

(I tried adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` too just to see if it changes anything and it didn't)

I need a solution which works with `singleInstance` and which does not require manual `finish()`.

**Update 1: I try to launch this `Intent`from a `SingleTop` activity (but changing it changes nothing)**

**Update 2: I try this on Android 2.3.3 emulator**

Comment: There is currently a bug that prevents FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP from working under lollipop, as far as I know. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @jvrodrigues Thank you for this information, unfortunately I try this on Android 2.3.3 which is the minimum version I give support.

Comment: Hello @frankish did you find the solution i am stuck in same kind of situation..I want to clear all previous activities including activities having launchmode="singleInstance"

Answer (score 4):

You can try finishAffinity(), it closes all the previous activities from stack

Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
finishAffinity()
startActivity(intent);
```